# How to determine if a full collection scan has been done in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I understand that using the output of `.explain()` on a MongoDB query, you can look at the difference between `n` and `nscanned` to determine if a full collection scan has been performed, or if an index has been used. [The docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain/) state

> You want `n` and `nscanned` to be close in value as possible.

[Kyle Banker's excellent book MongoDB in Action](http://www.manning.com/banker/) says something very similar:

> Generally speaking, you want the values of `n` and `nscanned` to be as close together as possible. When doing a collection scan, this is almost never the case.

Clearly neither of these statements are definitive about comparing `n` and `nscanned`. What proportion of difference generally infers a full collection scan - 10%, 20%, 30%+? Are there any other ways to check if a full collection scan has been done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What proportion of difference generally infers a full collection scan - 10%, 20%, 30%+?

This is impossible to say but if it really matters a whole tonne then you could be seeing a performance degradation of up to 200% for an average find; so yes, you WILL notice it. It is much like any other database on this front.

> Are there any other ways to check if a full collection scan has been done?

You could start MongoDB with a flag that tells it to never do a full table scan, in which case it will throw an exception when it attempts to: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--notablescan

However the best way is to just to use `explain` here, you will know when a query does not use an index and is forced to scan the entire collection from either disk or memory.

Comment: But is it possible for a query to use an index and still perform a full collection scan?

Comment: @ssbrewster No it is not, however, performant use of an index is another thing you need to make sure of, using an index and using an index the right way are two different things

Comment: and this still holds true even if an index is only used to sort the results?

Comment: @ssbrewster Correction to my last statement, since I said two things in my first comment, I meant Yes as in the right way to use indexes do apply still but the answer could also be no in that my statement does not hold, if the index is only used for sort then yes an full table scan can occur.

Comment: @Sammaye thanks for confirming, so then I need to look at n vs nscanned?

Comment: @ssbrewster Indeed, you might also wanna look at nScannedObjects since that denotes how many actual documents were scanned because they didn't fit into an index.

Comment: Didn't fit into an index?  There is no such concept.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Hmm prolly should have said "fields" i.e.: an index that only covers `a` of `db.col.find({a:1,b:1})`

Comment: pattern match query can also lead to full index scan.

Answer (score 26):

The answers above are NOT completely correct.

A collection scan will also be performed where an index is used for sorting but cannot assist the match criteria. In such a case, all the docs are scanned (in index order) to find docs which match the find criteria. Another possibility is that there may be a partial collection scan, where the index is able to narrow the subset of docs according to one or more find criteria but still needs to scan this subset of docs to find matches for the full find criteria.

In these situations, explain will show an index being used and not BasicCursor. So whilst the presence of BasicCursor in explain is indicative of a collection scan being performed, the absence of it doesn't mean a collection scan was not performed.

Also, using --notablescan also won't help where an index is used for sorting. Because queries only raise an exception where an index is not used. It doesn't look for whether the index was used for the match or the sort.

The only foolproof method of determining whether a collection scan was performed is to compare the index keys with the match criteria from the query. If the index selected by the query optimiser (and shown in explain) is not capable of answering the query match criteria (ie different fields) then a collection scan is needed.

Comment: MongoDB will not perform a collection scan on index sorting, mongodb returns the order of the docs in the index unless the index does not exist in which case it will then do a collection scan, scanandorder in memory and then return those docs

Comment: If you have ever had this you will find 99% of the time you actually had scanandorder true which meant that the index was not used for sorting

Comment: You seem to only be considering the situation where the sort matches the find. Where you have an index which only supports the sort and you also do a match with a find then the index is used for sorting (the index is run through to obtain the sort order) but the document is still scanned/read in order to perform the match. Take for example docs of form {a:1,b:1} with an index on {a:1} but a find statement of db.test.find({b:1}).sort({a:1}). When there is no index on b the {a:1} index is used for the sort but the collection is still scanned in its entirety.

Comment: Your scenario uses a very specific one which goes against what the docs recommend and also what the OP said. If you follow the docs and make indexes to match your queries you would (should) never have a full collection scan while using an index

Comment: Also my answer goes upon an ideal scenario not one where the index only half covers so its not really wrong, you also explain your scenario in your answer since atm stating that a collection scan will always be used when an index is used for sorting is incorrect

Comment: Infact I actually mention your scenario i a comment: "ssbrewster if you were to make an index on b and then do: db.col.find({a:1}).sort({b:1}); then I can't see how it wont do a full table scan, but yeah" on the other answer

Comment: Sorry but I still have to disagree with both parts of the accepted answer. The notablescan will not work where an index is utilised by the query. The second point about looking at explain to see if an index was used is not determinative that a full collection scan was avoided (as explained above). The answer I gave above covers all scenarios not just those where queries follow best practice and the match and sort parts of the query are covered by the index. This is also how we teach it at Mongo University.

Comment: As a side note for those watching on, and for Mongo University students who come across this post, the OP's question only considered full collection scans - there are a much wider array of queries which would use an index and yet perform partial collection scans where at least one doc needs to be hit in order to fulfil the query. So its important to compare the index keys with your match doc to see if the index chosen is capable of answering your query or some docs would need to be scanned.

Comment: I actually wasn't arguing either of those points, what I was arguing was your English: "A collection scan will also be performed where an index is used for sorting." As I was trying to say, your English is misleading.

Comment: I will accept my answer is incorrect in that sense, that's a small bug within MongoDB which you'd only know if you spent that much time on the internals of explain, tbh I have never had to use the flag

Comment: I was replying to 'But is it possible for a query to use an index and still perform a full collection scan?' by ssbrewster as well as offering a complete answer. In that context I was referring to scenarios where the index selected is used for sorting but could not assist with ANY match criteria (full collection scan performed) or SOME match criteria (full/partial collection scan performed - depends on key order). Perhaps that wasn't clear and should have been 'A collection scan will also be performed where an index is used for sorting but cannot assist with all/some of the match criteria.'

Comment: Yeah that's clearer, atm it sounds like all cases of index sorting results in collection scan

Comment: I edited your post per your comment, @Matt. Also I note that on this rare occasion the Mongo docs are not very clear: "If no index supports the query, MongoDB must perform a collection scan." That implies that sorting must not use an index in order to scan. However, per their online training, that is not true. Quote is from; http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain-example-covered-query

Answer (score 1):

The definitive answer is in the first line of explain() output.

If it says cursor type is "BasicCursor" then it was a simple collection scan.

Otherwise it will say what type of index it used and the name of the index, I.e. "BtreeCursor *id*"

See the docs here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain/#explain-output-fields-core for same explanation.

Comment: But as I asked above, could a full collection scan still happen if an index is only used for sorting the results?

Comment: @ssbrewster if you were to make an index on `b` and then do: `db.col.find({a:1}).sort({b:1});` then I can't see how it wont do a full table scan, but yeah

Comment: @Sammaye thanks that makes sense...and back to the n vs nscanned thing then if I'm looking at a 30%-40% difference between the two I guess it's a pretty safe to say that a full collection scan has been done...and it's just smacked me in the face that this can be validated by just running count() on the collection and comparing with nscanned - correct?

Comment: @ssbrewster indeed you could run a count, 30-40% might not mean full table but could mean bad index usage. It really depends, this is something that comes with experience really.

Comment: @Sammaye yes thanks you're right it could be bad index usage too

Comment: if an index is used then collection scan is not done by definition.  however, the entire index may be scanned if it's not the right index for filtering results (but for sorting only).  that's why you should consider selectivity and ordering when designing your index strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly it seems that a full table scan has only been done when the cursor is basic cursor.

If there is a btree cursor, then possibly a full table scan may still effectively have been done to find records, with that btree index only having been used for sorting. Though, if looking at the output of explain, can you really be sure that it was a full table scan, without going and counting records and looking at the indexes existing.

What, in the context of the question would be clear, if that the query is not efficient and that a better index is needed, or should be hinted to.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the explain's stage (from MongoDB doc):

Stages are descriptive of the operation; e.g.

-COLLSCAN for a collection scan
-IXSCAN for scanning index keys
-FETCH for retrieving documents
-SHARD_MERGE for merging results from shards